# Inserting CSV data into SQL with commas

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, csv, ssis

I have an CSV file that I'm trying to load into SQL but commas are causing data to shift into different columns. I've added `"` to the text qualifier in the flat file properties in my SSIS package and the preview looks good but when I actually load the data, it doesn't seem to notice the `"` text qualifier rule.

Any ideas why there's a disconnect between the preview and when I actually load the data?

Comment: OK, you've got a CSV that you are loading into SQL via SSIS. What does this have to do with [excel]?

Comment: Idk, excel is what i'm using to edit the CSV file.

Comment: Have you tried converting the CSV file to SQL format? - load your CSV file into this and it'll convert the contents of the CSV file into SQL format - http://codebeautify.org/csv-to-sql-converter

Comment: @MuhammadSohailArif what is SQL format?

Comment: read above ^ and if you need more assistance, let me know :)

Comment: @MuhammadSohailArif its failing to load the data, but I'm not sure if this would help. The SSIS is not recognizing the " text constraint

Comment: Since " is a special character SQl Server ma be freaking out because of that. You could try taking the original file opening it in notepad and then do a find and replace and replace all the commas (,) with a tab ('  '). Then change the option to tab qualified.

Answer (score 0):

1. Visit http://codebeautify.org/csv-to-sql-converter.
2. In the 'Enter Table Name' field, type in a value that will be used to refer to the table.
3. Click 'Browse' and locate your .csv file.
4. The tool should convert data from the CSV file into an SQL format.

Hope this helps,

Sohail.